# unable to get previous date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, object, momentjs

I have the following date

`let api_date = '2022-03-01T00:00:00.000Z'`

Now, i want to get previous 2 dates starting from `api_date`. Basically now i need dates as `2022-02-28T00:00:00.000Z` and `2022-02-27T00:00:00.000Z`
Basically for api_date of 1st March, i need previous 2 dates as Feb 28th and Feb 27th.

I tried using this below code

```
let t-1 = moment().substract(1, 'days')
let t-2 = moment().subtract(2, 'days')
```

But this only provides previous 2 dates from the present date. i.e. present date is 2nd March, so it provides previous 2 dates based of 2nd March.

how can i use moment to get my current specified date and get previous 2 dates based on that. Any advice to achieve that ? i saw the documentation of moment.js too but i didnt find a definitive answer.

Comment: Just for info, moment.js is not maintained anymore. If you start a new project don't use moment. But if it's an old project, still use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a date object from the date you wanna parse like this,

```
let api_date = '2022-03-01T00:00:00.000Z'
var dateObj = new Date(api_date);
```

then you can create a moment object based on the date object just like this,

```
var momentObj = moment(dateObj);
```

then if you perfom your specific logic you will get your desired result, like this

```
 let date1 = momentObj.substract(1, 'days')
 let date2 = momentObj.substract(2, 'days')
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, you need to pass your date to moment. Otherwise it defaults to current date ( as you found out ).

```
let t-1 =  moment(api_date).subtract(1, 'days')
let t-2 =  moment(api_date).subtract(2, 'days')
```